# How can we migrate the DBF related code to C#.NET?

Tags: c#, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a code related to dbf operation in Visual foxpro as given below .

```
SELECT 3
USE student shared

SET FILTER TO

LOCATE FOR id=thisform.txtStudentID.Value
```

can any one help me to understand the each line of code and convert to C#.net.What are the steps to be taken to convert foxpro code to C# ? Here I am using SQL Server as backend in C# Project.Some times I have faced the below type of code also

```
Use Student Shared
```

// Here accessing the database fields directly.Here Are they targeting to get all records like "select * from student" or only last record.By default this student table has 6 columns but in the dbf file we have 12 columns. How can do this in C#.NET?

Comment: In your question above, you don't tell us what database you're wanting to target. Are you aiming to talk to a FoxPro DB from C# or have you exported your DB to some form of SQL-based DB?

Comment: lang ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5f4hyy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I believe there is a [FoxPro Data Driver for ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977092(v=vs.71).aspx) so that you can just pass the commands directly to your database through C# using ADO.NET. No conversion necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To answer part of your question - what does this code do...

The following sets a work area (I haven't done foxpro for a few years now, but think this is redundant in the later versions of VFP). A work area is just a space in memory which is kept sperate from other work spaces.

```
Select 3
```

The following opens a table called 'Student' for non-readonly access into the previously opened workspace

```
USE student shared
```

The following clears all filters on the table (so if you 'BROWSE' you will get all records)

```
SET FILTER TO
```

The following will set the record pointer to a specific record where the record with an id is equal to the txtStudentID textbox value on the current form (foxpro is not a strongly typed language)

```
LOCATE FOR id=thisform.txtStudentID.Value
```

For the second part of your question, there is no direct way to convert between foxpro and a c# application. The main points are that Foxpro is built around a database and is not strongly typed whereas c# is stongly typed and can access a database. If you do a quick google search you will probably find tools written by people like Markus Egger to convert from foxpro to c#.

IMHO and from experience of migrating an enterprise sized system from VFP to c# / SQL server - if you want to do this with a system - stop, convince yourself it is a bad idea and just re-write the thing in c# - picking a database that best suits your needs.

It's hard to comment further - you haven't stated what version of foxpro you are using - are you using foxpro or visual foxpro? What size is your application, what is the background?

HTH
Jay

Comment: Jay - conversions between string and integer DO NOT happen behind the scenes. Yes, re-writing it in another technology is absolutely the way to go but sometimes there has to be a transitional stage where that tech may need to access DBF data.

Comment: Some times I have faced the below type of code also

Use Student Shared 

// Here accessing the database fields directly.Here Are they targeting to get all records like "select * from student" or only last record.By default this student table has 6 columns but in the dbf file we have 12 columns. How can do this in C#.NET?

Comment: @AlanB Yes, you are right - was thinking about something completly different and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly convert that to C#.

```
SELECT 3
```

FoxPro has the concept of 'work areas' - like slots, each of which can have an opened DBF file in it. This command says "OK - we're looking at work area 3."

This has no equivalent in .NET

```
USE student SHARED
```

This will open student.dbf, in the current directory, for shared access in work area 3.

```
SET FILTER TO
```

If we have a filter set, which will limit what records are available, clear that filter now. Pointless, as we've just opened the table and we didn't set a filter.

```
LOCATE FOR id=thisform.txtStudentID.Value
```

Find the first record where id = thisform.txtStudentID.Value. The latter part is a custom property of the form that is running this code.

So all this code is doing is locating a record in student.dbf based on a value. If you wanted to pull that record back in C# using the OLE DB provider you could check [How to load DBF data into a DataTable.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24247/Load-a-DBF-into-a-DataTable)

Comment: Just want to point out that the LOCATE finds the _first_ record that meets the criteria. There could be others.

Answer (score 0):

The `SET FILTER TO` is not needed as the table is being used (opened) so there is no filter to clear. To convert this bit of FoxPro to C#:

`SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=thisform.txtStudentID.Value`

You would then have to loop the results (if any). Best practices would be to use a parameter for the `WHERE` clause value to prevent SQL injection.